# How to save login data in my iOS application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What I exactly want:

I have a login system. Whenever user logs into his account, the app gets a unique id as json response. 
Now what I want to do is to use this id in the whole app since the user accesses his profile using his/her unique id and sends `/rcvs` messages through the same unique id.

I need to carry this id throughout the app. Even when the app crashes or closes. After the user comes back to the app, the user is logged in directly without displaying the login screen. Also, this id is removed or becomes null only when user clicks the sign out button.

This is my code:
http://www.pastie.org/3848543

I believe I should use one of the following:

1. pList
2. NSUserDefaults
3. appDelegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can solve this by using nsuserdefaults ..

here's a sample code :

```
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"your-key-goes-here"] == nil)
        [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"your-key-goes-here"];
```

you can check your key exists like above and when you get the answer you can set it like above but of course using the method like :

```
[standardUserDefaults setValue:@"your-value" forKey:@"your-key-goes-here"];
```

and then finally you should synchronize the userdefaults like :

```
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

hope this helps..

Comment: response which i am getting is from server and every user has a unique id ...like if i log in, i will rev a unique id which should be used in other views like the profile view or for adding friends etc.

Comment: that id of course is a coding mechanism from server to php to Xcode something but i should be able to carry that unique id throughout the app. That id will be used to display users own contents which he has uploaded on the server and also that id will be responsible for sending friend requests etc,,

Comment: but initial task is to save that id on the device itself as a persistence store so that i can use it in every class to send requests to web service

Comment: you can carry your unique id throughout your application by appdelegate also but if you want to store the id when user exits the app or something like that you can use the above code with nsuserdefaults . it is not a temporary storage , you can store the value in all lifetime of your app on the device..

Comment: @irernk and if the user clicks on sign out, the value should be deleted..what should i do for that ...simply make NSUSerDefaults value null....

Comment: could you guys guide me to some sample applications source code... i have an app of WestSide Bar which is freely available and that uses exactly what i want for login system

Comment: yes you just call [NSUserDefaults setValue:nil forKey:@"your-key"] when user logs out and since you check if the key is nil at first you will know if the user is logged in or not.
the above code is the only example code you need for my solution ..
hope this helps..

Comment: Yes you should use this one only thats is best for that.

Comment: @iremk is NSDefaults a good option for persistence store..what i know is that NSDefaults is not used for persistence store.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong? I think that this problem could be solved via **cookie**
Set the id when user logs in and change it whenever you want?
Also, you can easy read the info in the cookie.

Comment: Instead of providing opiniated answers, provide something which can be counted upon

Answer (score 1):

sort fr late and use NSDefaults to store this id
and Second option is to add a property in app delegate and assign valut to it

Comment: app delegate value thing i am doing it right now as i need to carry the id throughout the app.... the thing is if app crashes or is shut down without logout, i need the user to automatically login back again without any login page credentials to be filled up

Comment: then store it into NSUserDefaults, user login credentials must be stored into NSUserDefaults quickly when user is authenticated

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the `NSUserDefaults`, and you suggested yourself. If you save it in any local file (such as an `plist`) you need to encrypt the file or the login data since it otherwise would be clearly available to anybody else to read (hence the security is low).

What you mean by using the `appDelegate` I am unsure about, since the `appDelegate` is nothing more than a delegate class. Use could make a delegate method for authenticating the user, but that would still bring you back to your initial question.

Comment: what abt sqlite 3.... is it safe to use..apple recommends almost never to use in your app....but what u guys think

Comment: True, but SQLLite has quite a bit of hassle as well. I would go with the NSUserDefaults and keep SQLLite for the major things that require much fetching and updating.

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if([standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"key"] == nil)
        [standardUserDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"key"];

[standardUserDefaults setValue:@"your-value" forKey:@"key"];

[standardUserDefaults synchronize];